# Screen Scraping in Python

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I'm new to the whole concept of screen scraping in Python, although I've done a bit of screen scraping in R. I'm trying to scrape the Yelp website. I'm trying to scrape the names of each insurance agency which the yelp search returns. With most scraping tasks, I'm able to perform the following task, but always have a hard time going forward with parsing the xml.

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=insurance+agency&ns=1&find_loc=Austin').read())

print soup
```

So when scraping a site, what are the steps that one should follow? Is there a set of necessary actions that one needs to take each time they attempt to scrape a site?

I'm running Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 10.10

I realize that this may be a poor SO question as outlined in the faq, but I'm hoping someone can provide some general guidelines and things to consider when scraping a site.

Comment: The only "necessary" actions are throttling yourself so that you don't interrupt the service for other people. Anything else depends entirely on your requirements.

Comment: Please describe what you mean when you say "have a hard time going forward with parsing the xml."  Do you mean you do not understand BeautifulSoup's api?  You can find documentation here http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html Do you mean that you do not understand the structure of the web page you are scraping and therefore do not understand how to programmatically extract elements from the page or when necessary perform additional get/post operations?  Are you having problems with python?

Comment: I meant that I don't understand the structure of the web page.

Comment: """I realize that this may be a poor SO question as outlined in the faq, but I'm hoping someone can provide some general guidelines and things to consider when scraping a site.""" - e.g. by doing basic research using the search box on SO. This question is really asked every other day...you'll find lots of solutions and answers yourself - hint: http://scrapy.org/ or you explain clearly why BeautifulSoup is not good enough for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend read up on xpath & try this scrapy tutorial. http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/tutorial.html . It is fairly easy to write a spider like this

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz.org"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
        "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
    ]
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    for site in sites:
        title = site.select('a/text()').extract()
        link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
        desc = site.select('text()').extract()
        print title, link, desc
```

Answer (score 2):

To ease the common tasks associated with screen scraping, a python framework "[Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)" exists. It will make html, xml parsing painless.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be experiencing is that you are having trouble parsing content that is dynamically generated with javascript. I wrote a small tutorial on this subject, this might help:

http://koaning.github.io/html/scapingdynamicwebsites.html

Basically what you do is you have the selenium library pretend that it is a firefox browser, the browser will wait until all javascript has loaded before it continues passing you the html string. Once you have this string, you can then parse it with beautifulsoup.