# Extract real-time data in Python from application without API

Tags: python, real-time, screen-scraping

I have an application/software which streams real-time data at a high speed. It's time & sales for those who are familiar with trading software. What are the ways to extract this data without much delay in order to process it and then store locally using Python?

I checked other similar questions, but they all seem to be about websites:
[Screen Scraping in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529633/screen-scraping-in-python), 
[Extract real time data from ajax website in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090997/extract-real-time-data-from-ajax-website-in-python).
My question is about extracting data from software without API.

You can see how a typical time & sales window looks like anywhere in the middle of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8t_4gTuzsfo

Comment: How exactly does the app/software stream data and what do you need to do with it?

Comment: In fact, i don't know internal implementation of how this program works. For me as a user, it shows a new stock price at which the last trade was made with additional info like size, time, market center. It streams this data several times per second (but actually this frequency depends on a particular stock). I need to extract this data in order to make some calculations, then store it.

Comment: I meant to ask the streaming method (websockets / HTTP / pub/sub). Do you have to continuously poll the app or some other way?

Comment: I don't know the streaming method, you just launch the software and then a user is supposed to visually see data and make decisions. I do not have to do anything else, i.e. poll the app. But if you want to see time & sales for another stock you type in another stock symbol into the window after which you receive streaming data for this new stock. It seems that I need some screen scraper?

Comment: You have to use the same source the app does to get data. Screen scraping is not reliable.

Comment: And if I do not have access to the source, are there other ways to somehow extract the data?

Comment: No easy way as far as I know. Consider using some real-time trading API: http://www.programmableweb.com/news/96-stocks-apis-bloomberg-nasdaq-and-etrade/2013/05/22